# Is attaching 100 devices to Azure IoT Hub and create an Azure Event Hub per device a good idea

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I want to connect around 100 (more coming) devices to the Azure IoT Hub. At the moment I try to figure how to assemble the different components (IoT Hub, Event Hubs, EventHub partitions etc).

Each device sends state changes (from 100 to 8640 times a day) that I have to accumulate. For example, it might be the case that the device sends 3 messages, and only after the third message, I can conclude that the measured temperature is 30 degrees. Thus, when connecting to the IoT Hub, I need the events per device in order. Once the temperature, or any other measured value, is calculated I want to publish this event. Again, the consumers of the calculated values need the events in order.

Thinking in Kafka terms, for me, the most logical thing would be to create two topics per device (for the device state changes and the calculated values). This would mean I need two EventHubs per device. I don't expect that the I need any form of parallel event processing, thus I would be fine with one partition per topic.

**Will the cost be different with two EventHubs per device than for using a single event hub for all devices?**
Is that way of setting things up a good idea, or would you do it differently?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need two Event Hubs, and use the DeviceID as  the partition key to enable in-order reads.

Cost aside you don’t want to provision and manage hundreds of Event Hubs.

Please read the excellent [Events, Data Points, and Messages - Choosing the right Azure messaging service for your data](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/events-data-points-and-messages-choosing-the-right-azure-messaging-service-for-your-data/) for an architectural overview of the different Azure Messaging options.  Your scenario may be better with some combination of Event Hub and Service Bus Topics.

By the way, almost all pricing questions are easily answered by using the [Azure Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/)